# Colocar uma linha do GridView com cor vermelha caso uma célula tenha o valor falso

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Gostaria de que uma determinada linha de meu `GridView` fique vermelha caso a célula correspondente da coluna closed esteja com valor falso.

Meu ASP.Net está assim:

```
div class="GridMain">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvInformationPeriod" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="GridViewUser" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        GridLines="None" ForeColor="#333333" OnPageIndexChanging="gvInformationPeriod_PageIndexChanging" onrowdatabound ="gvInformationPeriod_RowDataBound" PageSize="100">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridAlternativeUser" BackColor="White" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PeriodID" HeaderText="PeriodID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SchoolID" HeaderText="SchoolID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOpen" HeaderText="Aberto Em" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="Usuario" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PCName" HeaderText="PC Name" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Closed" HeaderText="Closed" />
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#62AFC1" CssClass="GridPagerUser" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
```

Meu ASPX.CS carrega o `GridView` assim:

```
 private void ListarGridInformationPeriod()
    {
        if (ddlSchool.SelectedValue != "")
        {
            gvInformationPeriod.Visible = true;
            gvInformationPeriod.DataSource = Period.ListOpenPeriod(int.Parse(ddlSchool.SelectedValue));
            gvInformationPeriod.DataBind();
        }
    }

protected void gvInformationPeriod_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlSchool.SelectedValue))
        {
            gvInformationPeriod.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            gvInformationPeriod.DataSource = Period.ListOpenPeriod(int.Parse(ddlSchool.SelectedValue));
            gvInformationPeriod.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Pensei em colocar alguma coisa conforme abaixo usando o `RowDataBound` mas não funcionou

```
protected void gvInformationPeriod_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {                
            if (e.Row.Equals("false"))
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

Tentei usar o conteúdo desse post mas não entendi bem

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048762/change-gridview-row-color-based-on-condition-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Solução:***

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
           if (e.Row.Cells[1].Text.Equals("false"))
           {
                e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName("red");
           }
      }
}
```

Aonde o **1** seria a **segunda** coluna do seu *GridView*.

Answer (score 2):

Você quase acertou faltou falar qual campo vc quer especificar o valor.
Ex: Quando o valor da `coluna` for false fica vermelho a linha.
ambos em  `protected void GridView1_RowDataBound`

**Modo 1:**

```
Label lbl1= (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Closed");
if(lbl1.Text = "false")
{
e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

**Modo 2:**

```
DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
  if (dr[1].ToString() == false) //o número é o ID da coluna [0,1,2, etc
{
//seu código
}
```

Comment: Eu quero 'pintar de vermelho' toda a linha que contiver o valor na coluna Closed como false. Valeu.

Comment: manda bala que vai funcionar perfeitamente.